# Capture double click on Yii's CGridView row

Tags: javascript, gridview, yii

I'm using this simple Javascript code (attached as string to [`CGridView.selectionChanged`](http://www.yiiframework.com/doc/api/1.1/CGridView/#selectionChanged-detail) property):

```
'function(id){location.href = update?id="+$.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection(id);}'
```

to capture click on any grid view's row and redirect user to `update` action for that particular row's entry.

How can I change it to react on double click only? `CGridView` exposes only `selectionChanged` event, no `click` or `dblclick`.

**EDIT**: If I should do this in pure jQuery / Javascript, then which selector to use, to make sure, that double click event will be bind correctly to all CGridView's rows and what kind of jQuery code to use, to obtain an ID necessary for building up the route.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

As mentioned in my question, `CGridView` exposes only `selectionChanged` own event, no `click` or `dblclick`, so this seems to be a wrong path. It seems, that the only way is to caputre this yourself.

Capturing `dblclick` on `CGridView` is an easy task:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('body').on('dblclick', '#files-grid tbody tr', function(event)
        {
            //Do something...
        });
    });
</script>
```

Where `#files-grid` is an ID of your `CGridView`, given in `id` key of its configuration array.

Obtaining the ID of model / row / record, that was clicked also seems to be an easy task:

```
var rowId = parseInt($.fn.yiiGridView.getSelection('files-grid')[0]);
```

Unfortunately, this approach is unreliable (if not: totally wrong), because it is 100% based on selection currently made by user in grid view. If you drop id to console (`console.log(rowId);`) and begin to click over and over all the time on the same grid view's row, you'll soon notice, that you're getting correct values only every second click. In all other time, you're gettin `NaN`.

Why? Quite simple. This method is based on selection and every second click removes selection from current row. Take a look at [`jquery.yiigridview.js` implementation](https://code.google.com/p/zii/source/browse/trunk/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js?r=65) for more details.

So, we need to come with something better, more reliable. Analysing [`getSelection` method in above mentioned `jquery.yiigridview.js` code](https://code.google.com/p/zii/source/browse/trunk/widgets/assets/gridview/jquery.yiigridview.js?r=65#92) got me some clue and I've came with something like that:

```
$('body').on('dblclick', '#files-grid tbody tr', function(event)
{
    var
        rowNum = $(this).index(),
        keys = $('#files-grid > div.keys > span'),
        rowId = keys.eq(rowNum).text();

    console.log(rowId);
});
```

This code is totally selection-independent and you should *always* get correct value of `rowId`.

Now put it into URL change code:

```
location.href = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('files/manage/view'); ?>?id=' + rowId;
```

And... *voila*! You have redirection to your selected action, *with proper model's ID*, happening only on double click on any of your grid view's rows.

BTW: You can change `dblclick` event to `click` and use [`event.ctrlKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.ctrlKey) (or [`event.altKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.altKey) or [`event.shiftKey`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.shiftKey)), if you want, for example, to react on single click with `Ctrl` (or `Alt` or `Shift`) key pressed on keyboard. You can check, if [`event.which`](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/) is equal to `2` (or `3`), if you want to react on middle (or right) mouse button click (only in jQuery, which normalizes this property -- [details](http://api.jquery.com/event.which/)).

Here is the entire code, for reference:

```
<script>
    $(document).ready(function()
    {
        $('body').on('dblclick', '#files-grid tbody tr', function(event)
        {
            var
                rowNum = $(this).index(),
                keys = $('#files-grid > div.keys > span'),
                rowId = keys.eq(rowNum).text();

            location.href = '<?php echo Yii::app()->createUrl('files/manage/view'); ?>?id=' + rowId;
        });
    });
</script>
```

Of course, this is written for learning purposes. For production version of your application, you should write a more generic code (so it could be attached to any grid view), migrate it to an external `.js` file, minify and obsfucate it and do a few other things.